# Check if filter element is expanded or collapsed

Tags: excel, vba

Following code is the HTML code of the element:

```
    div id="docTypeForm:filterPnl" class="rf-cp rf-tgp" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"
        input id="docTypeForm:filterPnl-value" name="docTypeForm:filterPnl-value" type="hidden" value="true"
```

Filter element:

[image: Filter element]

I`m trying to have a code that checks if the value of this filter is true or false. I've tested multiple options without succes I can return all values from the first line but nothing from the second where the value is located.

Here are some samples that i've tried, it is somewhat messy:

```
'Set check = obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:filterPnl-Value")


'MsgBox obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:filterPnl").getAttribute("value")


'If obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:filterPnl-Value").isVisible = False Then
'        MsgBox False
'Else
'MsgBox True '

'End If
```

How can I enter in the second line with 'input id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using the getElementsByName wrongly:
This one fixed it

```
 If obJIE.Document.getElementsByName("docTypeForm:filterPnl-value")(0).Value = True Then
```